# How to resolve dependents of a python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, setuptools

After [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73773454/why-it-fails-when-i-want-to-add-cli-to-my-python-project),I added this to my setup.py:

```
install_requires=['pytest>=7.1.3','setuptools>=63.4.1','click>=8.1.3','geopandas>=0.11.1','bidict>=0.21.2','multidict>=6.0.2','networkx>=2.8.6','pandas>=1.4.3','shapely>=1.8.4'],
classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Natural Language :: English',
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
    'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy',
],
```

However the powershell still told me this message:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUserName>  pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ dijkstra-conda==45097613
……
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting dijkstra-conda==45097613
Using cached ……dijkstra_conda-45097613-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest>=7.1.3 (from dijkstra-conda) (from versions: 0.0.0.dev1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest>=7.1.3

PS C:\Users\MyUserName> pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ dijkstra-conda==45097613
……
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting dijkstra-conda==45097613
Using cached ……dijkstra_conda-45097613-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geopandas>=0.11.1 (from dijkstra-conda) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for geopandas>=0.11.1
```

So how to resolve this problem?

Comment: using conda and pip together ? and use pypi official artifactory not test one

Comment: Yes I have done this，see my answer.

Comment: use pipenv or pdm , than conda or pip

Comment: No，pdm still crashed as installing with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't download from testpypi，if you want to get packages，please use pypi.

And geopandas must be installed from conda.